# Look up first satisfying condition in array of data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to come up with a solution to the following problem: I have two sets of data. One table contains some levels and the points required for a player to reach each level. The other table has, for each day played, how many points the player has.

| Level | Points Required |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 3000 |
| 3 | 6000 |
| 4 | 10000 |

| Day | Points |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1200 |
| 2 | 2900 |
| 3 | 3500 |
| 4 | 7000 |

I want to figure out at what level a player is at a given day. This is the expected output for this:

| Day | Level |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

I am trying to do this: for each day, take the points and find the greatest value in the Points Required row that is still smaller or equal than the points on that day, and return the equivalent level. Do I use Query, Arrayformula, a combination? Can anyone provide a solution?

Answer (score 1):

a combination of ARRAYFORMULA() and a VLOOKUP(,,,TRUE) structure should suffice.

[Here is a sheet created specifically for this question](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WS9c1FzB7gIc_c5TH9KKcHWCiq0DFZN7iaaujvK1oWs/edit#gid=2100307022).  Editing will remain open to all for 30 days.  Take a look at this formula on Sheet1, cell C1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(B1:B)=1,"Level",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1:B,Sheet2!A:B,2,TRUE))))
```

You can read more about [VLOOKUP() here](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en).